# efibootmgr is not selecting the right drive/partition

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, efi, refind

I have an issue adding an rEFInd entry to my boot list, or to be more precise, I'm able to add it, but it selects the wrong disk (even tho I selected another one with the `-d` parameter.)

Take a look at my Drive/Partition Layout (removed a few other drives to simplify):

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb           8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0    64M  0 part /boot/efi_fallback
├─sdb2        8:18   0 911.5G  0 part /
└─sdb3        8:19   0    20G  0 part [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   238G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   256M  0 part /boot/efi
```

I have Arch installed on `/dev/sdb2` and an esp fallback with GRUB & rEFInd on `/dev/sdb1`. I have Windows 10 on `/dev/nvme0n1p1` and Windows Bootmanager & my rEFInd I want to boot to on `/dev/nvme0n1p2`.

Now check efibootmgr -v output:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0009,0003,0008
Boot0001* GRUB  HD(1,GPT,32b82bd9-4f63-3b40-b1d0-6138178779f0,0x800,0x20000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi)
Boot0003* rEFInd Fallback   HD(1,GPT,32b82bd9-4f63-3b40-b1d0-6138178779f0,0x800,0x20000)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0008* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........k.W.D.C. .W.D.S.2.5.6.G.1.X.0.C.-.0.0.E.N.X.0....................A............................D.DI..........Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.8.0.6.9.3.8.0.5.9.1.6........BO..NO........u.W.D.C. .W.D.2.0.E.Z.R.Z.-.0.0.Z.5.H.B.0....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . .W. .-.D.C.W.4.C.5.M.P.X.3.N.F.X........BO..NO........u.O.O.S.1.0.0.0.G....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0. . . . . . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot0009* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,1c744bb0-b45d-4983-96c9-f9ca59f6f9fc,0x1dbf3000,0x80000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
```

As you can probably see, `HD(1,...` is `/dev/sdb1` and `HD(2,...` is `/dev/nvme0n1p2`. Now I want to add my rEFInd to the efibootmgr (Path: `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi`) with the following command:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1p2 -l "\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi" -L "rEFInd Boot Manager"
```

If I now check the output of `efibootmgr -v` I get this:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0009,0003,0008
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(1,GPT,0fcf005d-a174-4f63-8d63-f41cbe5bd0aa,0x8800,0x1dbea800)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0001* GRUB  HD(1,GPT,32b82bd9-4f63-3b40-b1d0-6138178779f0,0x800,0x20000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi)
Boot0003* rEFInd Fallback   HD(1,GPT,32b82bd9-4f63-3b40-b1d0-6138178779f0,0x800,0x20000)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0008* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........k.W.D.C. .W.D.S.2.5.6.G.1.X.0.C.-.0.0.E.N.X.0....................A............................D.DI..........Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.8.0.6.9.3.8.0.5.9.1.6........BO..NO........u.W.D.C. .W.D.2.0.E.Z.R.Z.-.0.0.Z.5.H.B.0....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . .W. .-.D.C.W.4.C.5.M.P.X.3.N.F.X........BO..NO........u.O.O.S.1.0.0.0.G....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0. . . . . . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot0009* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,1c744bb0-b45d-4983-96c9-f9ca59f6f9fc,0x1dbf3000,0x80000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
```

The Issue now is that I specified the right disk/partition but the disk in `Boot0000` is `HD(1,...` but that is the wrong disk.

I have already tried to `umount /dev/sdb1` and then `refind-install --usedefault /dev/nvme0n1p2` but it didn't write to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is  a response two months after the original post, I'm not sure if you have made any progress on this. I'm not sure if what I will mention will even be completely accurate, as I am currently troubleshooting my EFI Boot Sequence.

But, from what I'm seeing in your command:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1p2 -l "\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi" -L "rEFInd Boot Manager"
```

You're not specifying the disk properly. As '/dev/nvme0n1p2' will point a loaded system directly at the second partition on the disk '/dev/nvme0n1'.

If my research is any kind of correct you will want to separate this into the proper options/arguments of '-d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 2', as '-d' specifies device and '-p' specifies partition number.

Comment: Am I right to assume this is a desktop PC, not a laptop? Have you checked if your second hard drive (the one with Windows on it) is not pysically set as slave?

Comment: Yes I have found a solution to the problem using the EFI Shell `bcfg boot add 0 fs1:\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi "rEFInd Boot Manager"`

But I didnt know that I had to specify the partition directly, I'll try that at some point.

Comment: Yes, this worked aswell